# zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance code

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I was trying to create a model using Tensorflow using the mnist dataset .
I have installed Tensorflow Properly and then when i try to create the model using the command .

```
python convolutional.py
```

I am getting an error message on the console :

```
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convolutional.py", line 316, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "convolutional.py", line 128, in main
    train_data = extract_data(train_data_filename, 60000)
  File "convolutional.py", line 75, in extract_data
    buf = bytestream.read(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * num_images)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 261, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 312, in _read
    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid block type
```

i am using Python2.7 installed in a 14.04 Ubuntu operating system .

Comment: what happened when you run gunzip data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz from command line (shell)? does it works?

Comment: @Yaron , i executed the command you mentioned , i.e ,sudo gunzip data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz , The message that i am getting is 
gzip: data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the source of the problem is invalid data file: "data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz". 
Is there any way to get a fresh copy of the file?
Please validate the new copy of the file using the following shell command:

```
gunzip -t  data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
```

Once the above test will return answer that the gz file is valid, execute your script:

```
python convolutional.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , will try that and let u know if that workd

Comment: Yup it did work , There was some problem with the file . so downloaded it again and then it was all good . thanks for your help .